# sql syntax error, but concatenated text runs fine in Datagrip

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a query, but I get an error when running it.

However, I'm using Intellij and when I use the copy string concatenation to clipboard feature, and run the query in the datagrip, the query runs fine (after putting in the parameters)

The error I am getting is "ERROR: syntax error at or near "tstoredarticle"\n Position: 199"

I find it a bit weird that it's showing there's a line change, after tstoredartiacle but besides that I don't see what's wrong.

What could be some issues that could cause a problem like that?

my query in intellij looks like this:

```
    private ResultSet getHuaweiSqlQuery(Integer intBrandID, Integer intStorageID, Vector<Integer> vecArticleTypes, int iCurrencyID, int iContactSupplierID, int secondaryStorage, BigDecimal exchangeRate) throws SQLException {
        return Hibernate3To4Utils.getConnection(session).createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT storedarticleid, "
                + " CASE WHEN storedarticle_storageid = " + intStorageID
                + " THEN id_storedarticleid_replacement ELSE"
                + " (SELECT COALESCE(id_storedarticleid_replacement, storedarticleid)"
                + " FROM etel.tstoredarticle x"
                + " WHERE tstoredarticle.storedarticle_articleid = x.storedarticle_articleid"
                + " AND x.storedarticle_storageid = " + intStorageID + ")"
                + " END as id_storedarticleid_replacement,"
                + " articlename,"
                + " articledescription, CASE WHEN price IS NULL THEN last_innprice*" + exchangeRate
                + " ELSE price END as last_innprice, id_modelids[1] as order_modelid, storedarticleamount-amount_in_order-amount_waiting as disponibelt,"
                + " amount_in_order, amount_in_bestilling, sum(tusedarticle.amount) as ant_artikler, articleid,amount_waiting, location"
                + " FROM etel.tstoredarticle"
                + " INNER JOIN etel.tarticle as b ON storedarticle_articleid = b.articleid"
                + " LEFT JOIN etel.tusedarticle ON usedarticle_storedarticleid = storedarticleid"
                + " AND ((tusedarticle.datesnap >= CAST(now() as date)-" + LOOK_BACK_DAYS
                + " AND usedarticlefromstorage = true) OR waiting = true)"
                + " LEFT JOIN etel.torder ON usedarticle_orderid = orderid AND torder.id_serviceplaceid = " + Constants.SERVICEPLACE
                + " LEFT JOIN etel.tsupplier_price ON id_articleid = b.articleid"
                + " AND tsupplier_price.id_serviceplaceid = " + Constants.SERVICEPLACE
                + " AND tsupplier_price.id_currencyid = " + iCurrencyID
                + " AND tsupplier_price.id_contactid_supplier = " + iContactSupplierID
                + " LEFT JOIN etel.tusedarticle as last_used on storedarticleid = last_used.usedarticle_storedarticleid"
                + " AND last_used.usedarticleid = (select MAX(latest_usedarticle.usedarticleid) from etel.tusedarticle as latest_usedarticle where"
                + " latest_usedarticle.usedarticle_storedarticleid = storedarticleid)"
                + " WHERE storedarticle_storageid IN(" + intStorageID + ", " + secondaryStorage + ") AND b.id_brandid = " + intBrandID
                + " AND id_articletypeid IN (" + getStringFromArray(vecArticleTypes.toArray()) + ")"
                + " AND tstoredarticle.passive <> true"
                + " GROUP BY storedarticleid,id_storedarticleid_replacement, articlename, articledescription, last_innprice, id_modelids[1],"
                + " storedarticleamount, amount_in_order, amount_in_bestilling, articleid,price,amount_waiting, location, last_used.datesnap"
                + " ORDER BY id_storedarticleid_replacement, storedarticleid");
    }
```

and here's the same query after using the copy string concatenation to clipboard feature:
(this runs fine)

```
SELECT storedarticleid, 
 CASE WHEN storedarticle_storageid = ?
 THEN id_storedarticleid_replacement ELSE
 (SELECT COALESCE(id_storedarticleid_replacement, storedarticleid)
 FROM etel.tstoredarticle x
 WHERE tstoredarticle.storedarticle_articleid = x.storedarticle_articleid
 AND x.storedarticle_storageid = ?)
 END as id_storedarticleid_replacement,
 articlename,
 articledescription, CASE WHEN price IS NULL THEN last_innprice*?
 ELSE price END as last_innprice, id_modelids[1] as order_modelid, storedarticleamount-amount_in_order-amount_waiting as disponibelt,
 amount_in_order, amount_in_bestilling, sum(tusedarticle.amount) as ant_artikler, articleid,amount_waiting, location
 FROM etel.tstoredarticle
 INNER JOIN etel.tarticle as b ON storedarticle_articleid = b.articleid
 LEFT JOIN etel.tusedarticle ON usedarticle_storedarticleid = storedarticleid
 AND ((tusedarticle.datesnap >= CAST(now() as date)-42
 AND usedarticlefromstorage = true) OR waiting = true)
 LEFT JOIN etel.torder ON usedarticle_orderid = orderid AND torder.id_serviceplaceid = ?
 LEFT JOIN etel.tsupplier_price ON id_articleid = b.articleid
 AND tsupplier_price.id_serviceplaceid = ?
 AND tsupplier_price.id_currencyid = ?
 AND tsupplier_price.id_contactid_supplier = ?
 LEFT JOIN etel.tusedarticle as last_used on storedarticleid = last_used.usedarticle_storedarticleid
 AND last_used.usedarticleid = (select MAX(latest_usedarticle.usedarticleid) from etel.tusedarticle as latest_usedarticle where
 latest_usedarticle.usedarticle_storedarticleid = storedarticleid)
 WHERE storedarticle_storageid IN(?, ?) AND b.id_brandid = ?
 AND id_articletypeid IN (?)
 AND tstoredarticle.passive <> true
 GROUP BY storedarticleid,id_storedarticleid_replacement, articlename, articledescription, last_innprice, id_modelids[1],
 storedarticleamount, amount_in_order, amount_in_bestilling, articleid,price,amount_waiting, location, last_used.datesnap
 ORDER BY id_storedarticleid_replacement, storedarticleid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation with dynamic text values to build a SQL statement.

For one, if the text values are supplied by a user, you're leaving yourself vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, allowing hackers to steal your data and delete your tables.

But you also have problems getting the text values quoted and escaped correctly.

Instead, use a `PreparedStatement`, where you place `?` markers anywhere a dynamic value needs to go. That is the string in the clipboard.

Example: You're doing:

```
String name = "John";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE name = " + name;
```

That gives you this text at runtime:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE name = John
```

which is wrong, because the text value needs to be quoted:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE name = 'John'
```

You could try

```
String name = "John's Cross";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE name = '" + name + "'";
```

but that's also wrong, because this new text value has embedded quotes and would produce:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE name = 'John's Cross'
```

To get it right, use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
String name = "John's Cross";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE name = ?";

PreparedStatement stmt = Hibernate3To4Utils.getConnection(session).prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setParameter(1, name);
return stmt.executeQuery();
```

The JDBC driver will take care of any escaping needed, and thereby protects you from both SQL injection attacks and SQL syntax errors.